# FluentAssertions: match each object of a collection

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

How to check that each object of a collection conforms to a given predicate? E.g.: check for each item (from a given collection) that it matches a given predicate (`MyPredicate`). Code should probably look something like this:

```
collection.Should().AllMatch(item => MyPredicate(item));
```

Is something like that available or do I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like Fluent Assertions 2.x does not support this scenario. Using Fluent Assertions 3.x one can use:

```
collection.Should().OnlyContain(predicate)
```